# Baire sets in 1-point compactification of uncountable discrete space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am trying to show that in the one-point compactification $X\cup\{\infty\}$ of an uncountable discrete space $X$, the Baire $\sigma$-algebra is strictly smaller than the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

The open sets consist of all subsets of $X$ and the subsets containing $\infty$ that are cofinite so these are the sets that generated the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. On the other hand, the Baire $\sigma$-algebra is generated by the compact $G_{\delta}$ sets, which I'm unable to give a full description of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’ll write $X^*$ for the one-point compactification of $X$ and $p$ for the non-isolated point. Of course every finite subset of $X^*$ is compact, and an infinite subset of $X$ is obviously not compact. Every subset containing $p$, however, is closed and therefore compact. Thus, the compact subsets of $X^*$ are the finite sets and the sets that contain $p$.

$G\subseteq X^*$ is a $G_\delta$ iff either $p\notin G$ (so that $G$ is actually open) or $X\setminus G$ is countable (so that $G$ is either open or the intersection of countably many open nbhds of $p$). The compact $G_\delta$ subsets of $X^*$ are therefore the finite subsets of $X$ and the co-countable sets containing $p$.

**Added:** Let $U$ be an uncountable subset of $X$ such that $X\setminus U$ is also uncountable; $U$ is open in $X^*$ and is therefore a Borel set. However, the Baire $\sigma$-algebra consists of the countable subsets of $X$ and their complements and therefore does not contain $U$.